# CorePlot hosting view and CPTXYGraph frame issues

Tags: macos, xcode5, core-plot

I'm trying to set up a simple pie chart in my OSX project, in Xcode 5, following the tutorial at :http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1.

The problem is that the graph doesn't show and both the CPTGraphHostingView and the CPTXYGraph have a height and width of 0.00.

Here is the code I use, after which I should be able to see the title for the graph in the view. The hostView is a reference to an NSView in the xib file.

```
-(void)configureHost {
self.graphHostingView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *)[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1103, 532)];

NSLog(@"%f", self.graphHostingView.frame.size.width);

[hostView addSubview:self.graphHostingView];
```

}

```
-(void)configureGraph {
NSRect parentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1103, 532);

//create graph
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] init];
[graph setFrame:parentRect];
NSLog(@"%f", graph.frame.size.width);
self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0f;
graph.paddingLeft = 0.0f;
graph.paddingTop = 0.0f;
graph.paddingRight = 0.0f;
graph.axisSet = nil;

//text in graph
CPTMutableTextStyle *textStlye = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
textStlye.color = [CPTColor grayColor];
textStlye.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
textStlye.fontSize = 16.0f;

//graph title
graph.title = @"Title";
graph.titleTextStyle = textStlye;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -12.0f);

self.theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
```

}

Not as important, but I'm also getting an error when I use the kCPTPlainWhiteTheme const, or other theme consts. a thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0).

It's probably an obvious issue but I just cant see it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception is probably a linking problem. How is the Core Plot framework added to your project? What version are you using? The view size issue is probably something in the way the view is configured in the xib.

Comment: I did have issues adding the CorePlot docset to my project so I downloaded a sample CorePlot project then added the framework straight to my project. Just by dragging to my project.

Comment: The custom vie is in a nswindow separate to the main window. I dont know if that makes much difference. It become the key window when it loads and accepts responder stuff

Comment: The CorePlot version is 1.4 and it's xcode 5

Comment: After more testing, it seems that the CorePlot classes aren't actually being allocated or initialised.

Comment: I worked it out. It was a library linking problem.